# How to fix type error when drawing a line with Mapbox

Tags: angular, typescript, mapbox-gl

I'm working on a project in which I use the Mapbox API to show cycling routes.

I followed Mapbox's own example on the API, which can be found here:

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-line/

Somehow I am having an error which seems to be caused by incorrect type but I really dont understand it, let alone solve it.

This code works, just like in the example.

```
this.map.addLayer({
      id: 'geojson',
      type: 'line',
      source: {
        type: 'geojson',
        data: {
          type: 'Feature',
          properties: {},
          geometry: {
            type: 'LineString',
            coordinates: [
              [-122.48369693756104, 37.83381888486939],
              [-122.48348236083984, 37.83317489144141],
              [-122.48339653015138, 37.83270036637107],
              [-122.48356819152832, 37.832056363179625],
              [-122.48404026031496, 37.83114119107971],
              [-122.48404026031496, 37.83049717427869],
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      layout: {
        'line-join': 'round',
        'line-cap': 'round'
      },
      paint: {
        'line-color': '#888',
        'line-width': 8
      }
```

But when I remove the hardcoded geopoints and change it with an array of LatLong values, based on the earlier API call I made to Mapbox to get a cycling route, I am getting an error:

```
this.map.addLayer({
      id: 'geojson',
      type: 'line',
      source: {
        type: 'geojson',
        data: {
          type: 'Feature',
          properties: {},
          geometry: {
            type: 'LineString',
            coordinates: this.directionsResult.routes[0].geometry.coordinates
          }
        }
      },
      layout: {
        'line-join': 'round',
        'line-cap': 'round'
      },
      paint: {
        'line-color': '#888',
        'line-width': 8
      }
    });
```

The error message is:

```
(property) mapboxgl.Layer.source?: string | mapboxgl.GeoJSONSourceRaw | mapboxgl.VideoSourceRaw | mapboxgl.ImageSourceRaw | mapboxgl.CanvasSourceRaw | mapboxgl.VectorSource | mapboxgl.RasterSource | mapboxgl.RasterDemSource
Type '{ type: string; data: { type: string; properties: {}; geometry: { type: string; coordinates: LatLong[]; }; }; }' is not assignable to type 'string | GeoJSONSourceRaw | VideoSourceRaw | ImageSourceRaw | CanvasSourceRaw | VectorSource | RasterSource | RasterDemSource'.
  Type '{ type: string; data: { type: string; properties: {}; geometry: { type: string; coordinates: LatLong[]; }; }; }' is not assignable to type 'GeoJSONSourceRaw'.
    Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"geojson"'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1298, 9): The expected type comes from property 'source' which is declared here on type 'Layer'.
```

When I compare the notation of the hardcoded geopoints with my result I get back from the Directions API, they appear to have the exact same type and notation:

```
let coords = this.directionsResult.routes[0].geometry.coordinates;
let geometry = [
      [-122.48369693756104, 37.83381888486939],
      [-122.48348236083984, 37.83317489144141],
      [-122.48339653015138, 37.83270036637107],
      [-122.48356819152832, 37.832056363179625],
      [-122.48404026031496, 37.83114119107971],
      [-122.48404026031496, 37.83049717427869]
    ];

console.log(coords);
console.log(geometry);
```

Which gives me the following console output:

```
(17) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
map-box.component.ts:94 

(6) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
```

Anybody with some help suggestions on what I am doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but when I add the waypoints to an empty array object and use that one it works:

```
let coordsArray = new Array(0);

for (let item of this.directionsResult.routes[0].geometry.coordinates) {
  coordsArray.push(item);
}
```

And then when adding the route Layer to the map:

```
this.map.addLayer({
      id: 'geojson',
      type: 'line',
      source: {
        type: 'geojson',
        data: {
          type: 'Feature',
          properties: {},
          geometry: {
            type: 'LineString',
            coordinates: coordsArray
          }
        }
      },
      layout: {
        'line-join': 'round',
        'line-cap': 'round'
      },
      paint: {
        'line-color': '#198e46',
        'line-width': 3
      }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try installing `@types/mapbox-gl` and `@geojson`:

```sh
npm install @types/mapbox-gl --save

npm install @types/geojson --save

npm install geojson --save
```

All your issues will be resolved.

Comment: Didn't work for me